# Adobe Animate Starling Error

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework, adobe-animate

I have created hungryherogame (recreate) in adobe animate using starling framework..
download from this address below :

( http://www.test.farsvila.ir/animate_starling_Error.rar )

```
package {
    import flash.display3D.textures.Texture;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;

    import starling.textures.Texture;
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.events.Event;
    import starling.display.Image;
    import starling.display.Button;
    import starling.core.Starling;
    import starling.events.Event;
    import screens.Welcome;

    public class Assets {

        [Embed(source = "media/graphics/bgWelcome.jpg")]
        public static const BgWelcome: Class;

        [Embed(source = "media/graphics/welcome_hero.png")]
        public static const WelcomeHero: Class;

        [Embed(source = "media/graphics/welcome_title.png")]
        public static const WelcomeTitle: Class;

        [Embed(source = "media/graphics/welcome_playButton.png")]
        public static const WelcomePlayBtn: Class;

        [Embed(source = "media/graphics/welcome_aboutButton.png")]
        public static const WelcomeAboutBtn: Class;

        private static var gameTextures: Dictionary = new Dictionary();

        public static function getTexture(name: String): Texture {
            if (gameTextures[name] == undefined) {
                var bitmap: Bitmap = new Assets[name]();
                gameTextures[name] = Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            return gameTextures[name];
        }
    }

}
```

Its made an error --> Call to a possibly undefined method fromBitmap through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: please provide some code, be sure, no one will not download that RAR file, so this question cant be solved until you posting that part of code which generates that error message.

Comment: Will do that bro :)

Comment: مرسی زیاد کدهاشم میذارم

Comment: ok thanks :) , also that down vote is not mine, unfortunately speaking Farsi is not allowed here but in chat.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Appreciate bro .oh never mind you are positive :) .My part of code was add to my post.pleas check it and help me to

Comment: How can i fine chat about as3 and starling framework ?

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here !! :/

Comment: only `1rep`. is it really first time using **StackOverflow**? you need more efforts :D

Comment: Hi @payam_sbr I cant connect to a server URL to send and receive variable using URLRequest URLLoader and so ... its working on local host but when i put all code in air for android and access internet in permission its not work at all !? can You Help me , i posted new question also .. Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 2):

in first look, every thing is OK! according [DOC](http://doc.starling-framework.org/current/starling/textures/Texture.html) `fromBitmap` is a public static member of `starling.textures.Texture`

but problem is because of `import flash.display3D.textures.Texture`  which is out of code block in your post and make me hanged some minutes !

so in this case, we have same class names, two Textures. compiler get mixed up  too (Ambiguous reference Error).

try it

### Edited

```
public static function getTexture(name: String): starling.textures.Texture {
    if (gameTextures[name] == undefined) {
        var bitmap: Bitmap = new Assets[name]();
        gameTextures[name] = starling.textures.Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    return gameTextures[name];
}
```

to make it clear for compiler, which Texture is your mean

### Suggestion

i guess you don't really need `import flash.display3D.textures.Texture;`
so remove it from your default code (problem solved without changing `Texture` to `starling.textures.Texture`)

Comment: @Mohammadtavakoly we have to change all Textures to starling.textures.Texture, i'll edit my answer right now

Comment: Y? we added it to class and extended from tow super class starling.textures !

Comment: @Mohammadtavakoly did you tried my edited code ? also read additional suggestion which is another answer (not related with first section)

Comment: @Mohammadtavakoly also if you need more discussion, join Here [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130317/discussion-between-payam-sbr-and-maziar) when you was >20 Rep's

Comment: @Mohammadtavakoly Good, so this answer is solved and should be accepted, but for your new problem, post it as a new question, unfortunately i'm not familiar with **starling-framework** and **stage3d**.

Comment: Thank you . i saw myself in your chat.

Comment: When it possible to write new one i will ask, accept my Appreciation

Comment: Imposible to live any comment there.(n chat room)

Comment: Hi Payam your sugestions was really useful.nowadays im working whith java .then ill start as3 .so i dont know   why stage3D was added to my code! Thanks and best regards .